# no definition for "Action" on a dynamic?

Tags: c#, exception, dynamic

I've got an event here that is fired with an argument that contains a *dynamic* object. It's an anonymous object directly created in the event call itself, like

```
if(MyEvent != null) MyEvent(this, new SensoricDataEventArgs { Data = new { Action = "Start", Team = "Blau" } });
```

where *SensoricDataEventArgs*'s signature is something like this:

```
class SensoricDataEventArgs : EventArgs {
  public dynamic Data { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to access that data in a handler (which is in another assembly, in case that's relevant), all I get is an exception that *object* doesn't have a definition for *Action*, even though I re-cast the Data property to *dynamic*. Even the DebuggerVisualizer for *dynamic* objects shows that there is a property *Action* on the object.

However, I get the mentioned exception.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do in the event handler, all together with the info from the debugger. In the image the debugger has stopped on a breakpoint. The next step throws the exception.

Any idea of what causes this exception? What am I doing wrong?
[image: MyEvent handler]

Comment: try to avoid dynamic
you could use a Dictionary instead of Data, containing Action as key and "Start" as Value. If that is not nesseary you should better do something like, creating an enum Action with Start, Running, Stopped,...

Comment: dynamic is mandatory here because of the architecture of "things" that might fire this event. There's a plugin system that I implemented myself that builds on it. Ah, and to add to that I use hosted IronPython/DLR in other places which also build on dynamic.

Comment: I'm with @thefiloe on this.  It seems like you wanted a "can do anything" object, which is always a bit vague and a bit of a sign that something hasn't been thought through properly.  If these things can contain a variety of different data, then you should look at how that is implemented.  Given that you say you implemented this plugin system yourself, I can't buy the "it's mandatory" reasoning :)

Comment: As mentioned below in my comment to mike's answer, I think, I'll reconsider how to implement the event... thanks to you as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that anonymous types are declared `internal`, so the members you are trying to access are not visible in your other assembly and the DLR actually does the same compile-time analysis on member accessibility at run-time. It will not let you access at run-time something you could not access at compile-time. It sees the anonymous type is `internal` and throws a `RuntimeBinderException`.

One solution is to write the reflection code explicitly rather than using `dynamic`. A more maintainable, long-term solution would be to remove `dynamic` from the event args and define more precisely how your components are communicating with each other.

Comment: Damn! Sorry... eh, alright... Looks like I really have to rethink my architecture... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would have been to use an *ExpandoObject* instead of an anonymous object.

In my particular case, and considering the fact that time is running short (deadline approaching), I'll use this workaround instead of rethinking my whole architecture and risking incompatibility of already completed plugins. It works and it preserves compatibility.

Comment: Or you could use normal named types instead. That shouldn't require you to change the architecture, since it will work with `dynamic`.

Comment: Probably. That would require developers of plugins to use normal types as well. Might be acceptable but less comfortable for them as they would have to write more code. Maybe I'll think about it after our deadline when there is more time again to improve those architectural flaws.